# Prolog change from a list to a conjunction

Tags: list, prolog

suppose i have a list

```
[p(X,Y) , h(n,U) , f(U,R)]
```

i want to change to a conjunction
and 
assign the conjunction to a variable
the output should be :
Output:

```
Variabile = p(X,Y) , h(n,U) , f(U,R)
```

you have any idea?

Comment: What do you expect in `Variable`? A boolean value? I don't think Prolog has such concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

```
list_to_conj([H], H) :- !.
list_to_conj([H | T], ','(H, Conj)) :-
    list_to_conj(T, Conj).
```

Usage examples:

```
?- list_to_conj([], Variable).
false.

?- list_to_conj([a], Variable).
Variable = a.

?- list_to_conj([a, b], Variable).
Variable = (a, b).

?- list_to_conj([p(X,Y) , h(n,U) , f(U,R)], Variable).
Variable = (p(X, Y), h(n, U), f(U, R)).

?- list_to_conj([writeln(hello), writeln(world)], Variable), call(Variable).
hello
world
Variable = (writeln(hello), writeln(world)).
```

Comment: oh my god Kaarel :D yes it is

Answer (score 2):

You can only assign terms to variables. Conjunction of terms is not a valid term.

Comment: (term, term) is a term. If you wanted something like this, then [term, term] would have been equally fine. Let's just say that you don't really understand what you want

Comment: yes ok i don't know what i want but someone gave me the right answer... -.-