# prolog term without a functor

Tags: list, prolog

I am facing a prolog problem regarding List and Term. Then my question is how to write a predicate

```
transform([a,b],X)
```

will return X = (a,b) Or vice versa

This is weird with me because I've never faced such term before. I tried with the built in =.. but

```
=..((a,b,c,d),X)
```

returns X=[',',a,(b,c,d)] which makes me deeply disappoint.
Thank you.

Comment: Do you want this to work for any number of elements in the list?

Comment: yes it should work for any number of elements. Actually I can't understand the return X=[',',a,(b,c,d)] of =..((a,b,c,d),X). For me, it should be X=[',',a,b,c,d]

Comment: It behaves similarly as a list with a head and another list as tail. In other words, `(a,b,c,d) = (a,(b,(c,d)))`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prolog change from a list to a conjunction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6808056/prolog-change-from-a-list-to-a-conjunction)

Answer (score 2):

Check something like this:

```
transform([A], A):-
  A=..[_].
transform([A,B], (A,B)):-
  B=..[_].
transform([A,B,C|Tail], L):-
  L=..[',',A,T],
  transform([B,C|Tail], T).
```

The first clause is only needed if you want transform([Item], Item).

```
?- transform([a,b], X).
X = (a, b) 

?- transform([a,b,c,d,e,f], X).
X = (a, b, c, d, e, f) 

?- transform(L, (a,b,c,d,e,f,g))
L = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```

Note that the term you are building does have a functor, it is ','/2, and it is shown with the parenthesis you are seeing.

Comment: Why do you have `L=..[',',A,T]` twice there?

Comment: It should only be the first one. I removed the second one. Thanks

Comment: oh I did not recognize that (a,b) is ,(a,b) because =..((a,b,c),X) gives X = [',',a,(b,c)] which is weird to me (I expected that X will be [',',a,b,c]). Then I just thought it is something like null(a,b) and lost 1 day to Google for it. Thank you gusbro.

Comment: the second thing is the =../2 give different answers for 2-arity predicate and more than 2-arity predicate like this,  22 ?- X=..[',',s,d].
X = (s, d).

23 ?- X=..[',',s,d,m].
X = ','(s, d, m). WHY :(

Comment: When you use `(a,b,c)=..L` it gives you `[',', a, (b,c)]` because the primary functor is ,/2 with the first argument `a` and the second argument `,(b,c)` which is shown as `(b,c)`.

Comment: In your second example `X=..[',', s, d, m]` you are building a term of arity three `','/3`, thus it will be `','(a,b,c)`. The interpreter only shows terms `','(a,b)` as `(a,b)`, i.e. only with primary functor `','` of arity two.

Comment: You can always replace `L = .. [',',A,T]` by `L = (A,T)` there is no difference whatsoever.

Comment: @false: You're right. You can remove the in the `L=..[',',A,T]` in the last clause and then replace the `L` in the head with `(A,T)`